# Error $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors or "No Bins"

Tags: r

I have a problem when use smbinning package.
I have dataset consists of ratio and Good_Bad:

ratio:

```
0.40    0.41    0.54    0.61    0.64    0.70    0.74    0.74    0.78    0.79    0.80    0.81    0.82    0.83    0.87    0.89    0.89    1.03    1.03    1.06    1.07    1.08    1.08    1.09    1.09    1.10    1.12    1.12    1.13    1.15    1.18    1.20    1.23    1.24    1.24    1.33    1.33    1.36    1.38    1.38    1.39    1.40    1.42    1.44    1.47    1.48    1.48    1.53    1.55    1.55    1.60    1.62    1.65    1.67    1.72    1.73    1.74    1.75    1.85    1.86    1.89    1.90    2.02    2.04    2.07    2.09    2.18    2.20    2.22    2.24    2.39    2.41    2.43    2.46    2.76    2.85    2.91    3.05    3.75    4.21    5.18    5.33    8.70
```

Good_Bad:

```
0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0
```

Code:

```
binning <- smbinning(df=dataset, y="Good_Bad", x="ratio", p=0.05)
binning$ivtable
```

> Error in binning$ivtable : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
>       binning
>       [1] "No Bins"

Why error and the result is "No Bins"?

Comment: Do you have a `data.frame` or `matrix`?

Comment: my data is data.frame

Comment: Please show the dput of your dataset

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the column "ratio" is stored as a numeric?

If it's stored as a factor or character you'd need to use

```
smbinning.factor()
```